# NetBeans adding classes, issue with multiple methods argument

Tags: java, netbeans

So I am using Netbeans for the first time and am having issues creating multiple classes and running them under my main function under the same project directory.  For instance, I am working through chapter 1 of a book, and would like to keep all my functions/classes under this directory.  However, I am running into issues because one class already is using the "main" method argument, so I am having difficulty calling my independent classes.

Here is two independent classes that I am sure compile, yet I need another script that calls them separately.

Below is function 1.

package chapter1;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author anthonycolombo60
 */
public class Chapter1 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations!");

}
```

}

How do I add a simple "HI" command that is called from the main?

package chapter1;

/**
 *
 * @author anthonycolombo60
 */
public class Chapter1 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hi!");
}
```

}

Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to have only one main class, and than call the other classes from an event like this:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
```

Meanwhile in the other class you should create a method:

```
public void hiCommand(){
System.out.println("Hi");}
```

now you should call the method in which you will have to create the hi command to the main class after calling the other class:

```
mc.hiCommand();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple classes with main methods in the same directory (package) with NetBeans, but they have to have different names for each class. You can run each class separately. To do this you right click on the class name in the Project window and choose "Run File" from the context menu or just put focus on the class name with your mouse or keyboard and press Shift+F6.